# getchar() got frozen while assigning the return value to a char array

Tags: c, getchar

I am doing my C assignment for colleage. The task is requiring the function uses getchar() to read input from user and save it to a char[] type variable. Here is my code:

```
void readLine(char str[], int length){
    
    int i = 0;
    if(length < 1) return;
    
    while(1){
        str[i] = getchar(); 

        if(str[i] == '\n'){
            str[i] == '\0';
            return;
        }
        if(i < length - 1) i++;
        
    }
}

printf("String? ");
char inputString[LENGTH];
readLine(inputString, LENGTH);
```

the terminal will get frozen while the value of getchar() is assigned to  str[i]. If I assigned it to an int type variable, no complains comes from terminal.
According to the doc of getchar(), it is returning int type and it is possible to assign to a char[]. So I am confused what I did wrong.

Comment: What exactly is `LENGTH`? How is it declared/defined? Without this information, what you show is not a [mre]...

Comment: `str[i] == '\0';` == this is a test for equality. For an assignment it is = `str[i] = '\0';`

Comment: Not the immediate issue, but think about what happens when end-of-file is reached.

Comment: @yuechen Liu, Save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is so simple:

1. instead of the line `str[i] == '\0';` it's `str[i] = '\0';` , not the difference between **=** and **==** , the first one is used in assignment , the second one is used to test whether the variable equals to this value or not.
2. you have a warning in this line `str[i] = getchar();` as `getchar()` returns `int` not `char` and my compiler gave me this warning :

> Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined

so you should cast the returned value from `getchar()` by writing `str[i] = (char)getchar();`

3. also , you should modify the condition `if(str[i] == '\n')` into `if(str[i] == '\n' || i == length - 1)`  , imagine that the user entered number of chars exceeded the `LENGTH` , then you should store only the first chars that could fit.

with these only 3 small modifications , this is the edited code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define LENGTH  10

    void readLine(char str[], int length)
    {

        int i = 0;
        if(length < 1) return;

        while(1)
        {
            str[i] = (char)getchar();

            if(str[i] == '\n' || i == length - 1)
            {
                str[i] = '\0';
                return;
            }
            if(i < length - 1) i++;

        }
    }

    int main(){

        printf("String? ");
        char inputString[LENGTH];
        readLine(inputString, LENGTH);
        printf("%s", inputString);
    }
```

and this is the output :

```
String?test
 test
```

Comment: *so you should cast the returned value from `getchar()` by writing `str[i] = (char)getchar()`;*  **NO** you should **NOT** do that.  `getchar()` returns `int` instead of `char` for a reason - `EOF` is typically a value that can not be represented as a `char`, but it can as an `int`.  When you force the value returned from `getchar()` into a `char`, you can no longer reliably detect `EOF`.  The original code posted in this question is broken, and pasting over that broken code with a cast only hides the fact the code is broken.